# Writing a Generic Wrapper: Conditionally Map different Types from Template Arguments onto a Single Class-Internal Type

Tags: c++, boost, wrapper, typedef, generic-programming

TL;DR: How can I perform conditional typedefs depending on the type of the template argument.

I am writing a Wrapper for different bitset implementations. For that I am referencing `std::bitset<>` and `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`. I observe that `boost::dynamic_bitset<>` follows the implementation of `std::bitset<>` by for example calling the proxy class for index handling returned by `operator[]` with a class called `reference`, just as `std::bitset<>` does. So, that is useful because in my wrapper -- that is templated with the bitset type `BITSET` -- I can then do

```
typename BITSET::reference operator[](INDEX_TYPE i)
    { return bitset[i]; }
```

and it will work for both, `std::bitset<>` and `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`.

However, there are features that are not parallelized like that. For instance declares `boost::dynamic_bitset<>` `typedef std::size_t size_type;` as the index type, as in:

`bool operator[](size_type pos) const { return test(pos); }`

But `std::bitset<>` simply uses `size_t` for that:

```
_GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR bool                                                                          
operator[](size_t __position) const
{ return _Unchecked_test(__position); }
```

So, in my Wrapper I could do `typedef size_t INDEX_TYPE` or something like that, but that might not work for another implementation that does not use `size_t`, as these two coincidentally (or not) do.

Obviously there is no really generic way to do this, but could I at least somehow conditionally define my `INDEX_TYPE`, akin to this:

```
template <class BITSET, class T>
/**
 *
 * @tparam T Use this parameter to pass on the template parameter that
 *         was used to template BITSET
 */
class BitsetWrapper
{
public: // typedefs
    if (typeid(BITSET) == bool::dynamic_bitset<T>)
        typedef tyeanme BITSET::size_type INDEX_TYPE;
    else if (typeid(BITSET) == std::bitset<T>)
        typedef size_t INDEX_TYPE;
    else if (typeid(BITSET) == BitSet<T>) // my own implementation
        typedef BITSET::INDEX_TYPE INDEX_TYPE;
    else
        throw std::invalid_argument("unsupported type: "+typeid(BITSET).name());
```

The above approach does not work and even if it did looks very clunky.

It is besides the point of my question, but just for completeness this is the error:

```
bitsetWrapper.hpp:34:5: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
    if (typeid(BITSET) == bool::dynamic_bitset<T>)
    ^
bitsetWrapper.hpp:36:5: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
    else if (typeid(BITSET) == std::bitset<T>)
    ^
bitsetWrapper.hpp:38:5: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
    else if (typeid(BITSET) == BitSet<T>)
    ^
bitsetWrapper.hpp:40:5: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
    else
```

I guess you can't just put conditionals randomly into the class space outside of functions, and this was the first time I ever tried this, because of the weird circumstances.

But how can this be approached correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `if/else` logic to defined a `typedef` like that. You can use a helper class to deduce it.

```
template <typename T> struct TypedefSelector;

template <typename T> struct TypedefSelector<boost::dynamic_bitset<T>>
{
   using IndexType = BITSET::size_type;
};

template <typename T> struct TypedefSelector<std::bitset<T>>
{
   using IndexType = size_t;
};

template <typename T> struct TypedefSelector<BitSet<T>>
{
   using IndexType = BITSET::INDEX_TYPE;
};
```

And then use:

```
template <class BITSET, class T>
class BitsetWrapper
{
   using INDEX_TYPE = typename TypedefSelector<T>::IndexType;
   ...
};
```

For typenames that don't have a `TypedefSelector`, you will get compile time error.

Comment: Thanks. It just came to my mind that I also could make `INDEX_TYPE` a template parameter, so then there would be no restriction to only 3 (or k for some k) types for `BITSET`, but the interface would be a little more cumbersome, because of the additional template parameter. What is better style though?

Comment: @lotolmencre, It's better to use the type deduction code. It is less error prone.